# Total size of bunch of gzip files folder

Tags: linux, gzip

I am trying to figure out the total size of a bunch of gz files inside of a folder.
I know that we can use gzip -l to get uncompressed size, but if you 
awk 'print $2' with that it returns uncompressed as well.

If I have 10 files inside a folder that are gz what would be best way to get uncompressed total?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the word "uncompressed" from the output, there are a few ways to do it.

Most simply, make the AWK command only process lines that aren't the first.

```
gzip -l *.gz | awk 'NR > 1 { print $2; }'
```